# Create Yosemite usb/dvd installer on ubuntu

Tags: macbook

I just installed Ubuntu on my Macbook and I did a mistake while installing so my hard drive is formatted. Now the OSX is gone.
I just downloaded Yosemite.dmg and I want to create a usb/dvd installer from Ubuntu. I want to install Yosemite back on my Macbook.
Is it possible to create a Yosemite DVD/USB installer in Ubuntu? If yes, how?

Comment: It is possible. Have a look [here](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/293168-guide-how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-109-mavericks-usb-install-drive-on-linux/) for instructions.

Comment: @RohithMadhavan Could you please post it as an answer?

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Have a look [here](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/293168-guide-how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-109-mavericks-usb-install-drive-on-linux/) for instructions.

Although the steps are for OS X Mavericks, it should also work fine with OS X Yosemite.